# SQL Query in pandas python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, pysqlite

I am writing an SQL query in python pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import numpy as np
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf=lambda q:sqldf(q,globals())
rolup = pysqldf(u"select MasterUserId,DeviceUsed,hcluster, count(MasterUserId) as Tot_Rec, sum(Visits),sum(PV),sum(TimeSpent) from clstrd_data group by MasterUserId,DeviceUsed,hcluster;")
```

Error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

How to switch to Unicode strings? I am using python2.7.

Comment: new code:                                                       import pandas as pd                                                           from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv                                    import numpy as np                                                       from pandasql import sqldf                                          pysqldf=lambda q:sqldf(q,globals()) rolup = pysqldf(u"select MasterUserId,DeviceUsed,hcluster, count(MasterUserId) as Tot_Rec, sum(Visits),sum(PV),sum(TimeSpent) from clstrd_data group by MasterUserId,DeviceUsed,hcluster;")

Comment: your "new code" is identical to what's in the question - so maybe delete your confusing comment here?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [python unicode howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html):

```
In Python source code, Unicode literals are written as strings prefixed with the ‘u’ or ‘U’ character: u'abcdefghijk'
```

In other words, your script should read:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import numpy as np
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf=lambda q:sqldf(q,globals())
rolup = pysqldf(u"select MasterUserId,DeviceUsed,hcluster, count(MasterUserId) as Tot_Rec, sum(Visits),sum(PV),sum(TimeSpent) from clstrd_data group by MasterUserId,DeviceUsed,hcluster;")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @hd1. I have changed my code but still getting exactly same error.

Comment: Sir I have just pasted you code. Because only differece i could see was addition of u before select statement. Here is the new code:                                                       import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import numpy as np
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf=lambda q:sqldf(q,globals())                          rolup = pysqldf(u"select MasterUserId,DeviceUsed,hcluster, count(MasterUserId) as Tot_Rec, sum(Visits),sum(PV),sum(TimeSpent) from clstrd_data group by MasterUserId,DeviceUsed,hcluster;")